# Why do my Highcharts stacked areaspline charts look funny?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, data-visualization

I'm building a dashboard application, using Highcharts for -well- charts. On high zoom levels, or on a short time interval, areaspline charts look all over the place.

I'm looking into interpolation options, coming from d3, but not finding much. Data are retrieved via AJAX to my API as a JSON, and rendered into the chart. A custom built modal switch can toggle data resolution between "year" and "hour", by running a new API request and refreshing the chart.

[data with 24-hour sampling rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Mmo.png)

[a detail of the same data, with 1-hour sampling rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4f3.png)

As visible from the screenshots above, in shorter sampling intervals when data variation is wider, the spline interpolation simply breaks, curves become straight line, spline points become angular and often areas and the delimiting curve are "decoupled".

I'm looking for a way to solve this, or at least to have the charts readable - in all formats. I can change the chart format (as long as it is stacked) but so far the area chart is the best fit for this kind of data.

A jsfiddle recreating the issue is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/_dario/s3o61gj4/

Here is the js code:

```
// this defines some colors 
var igColor = "#fec564",  //instagram 
twColor = "#55acee",  //twitter
fbColor = "#3b5998",  //facebook
wbColor = "#a48ad5",  //blog
wfColor = "#e57e31",  //forum
wnColor = "#17c457",  //news 
inColor = "#007bb5",  //linkedin
ytColor = "#ff1216",  //youtube 
otColor = "#81959b";   //others

//this defines the chart configuration with NULL data - data are added via AJAX later on

  var config = {
    chart: {
      zoomType:'x',
      height:500
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Ugly chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Posts'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled:true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [
    {
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Instagram',
      data: null,
      color:igColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Twitter',
      data: null,
      color:twColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Facebook',
      data: null,
      color:fbColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Blogs',
      data: null,
      color:wbColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'News',
      data: null,
      color:wnColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Forums',
      data: null,
      color:wfColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Youtube',
      data: null,
      color:ytColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Linkedin',
      data: null,
      color:inColor
    },{
      type: 'areaspline',
      name: 'Others',
      data: null,
      color:otColor
    }
    ] 
  }; //end config definition

//THESE DATA ARE ORIGINALLY RETURNED BY AN AJAX CALL TO MY API

var d = {
"ig":[[1550880000000,1],[1550883600000,1],[1550890800000,1],[1550898000000,1],[1550901600000,3],[1550905200000,1],[1550908800000,6],[1550912400000,6],[1550916000000,6],[1550919600000,9],[1550923200000,4],[1550926800000,7],[1550930400000,5],[1550934000000,5],[1550937600000,12],[1550941200000,8],[1550944800000,6],[1550948400000,7],[1550952000000,6],[1550955600000,3],[1550959200000,3],[1550962800000,4],[1550966400000,1],[1550970000000,1],[1550977200000,1],[1550988000000,3],[1550991600000,4],[1550995200000,6],[1550998800000,6],[1551002400000,9],[1551006000000,4],[1551009600000,9],[1551013200000,11],[1551016800000,9],[1551020400000,7],[1551024000000,6],[1551027600000,7],[1551031200000,4],[1551034800000,6],[1551038400000,9],[1551042000000,4],[1551045600000,6]],
"tw":[[1550880000000,1],[1550901600000,1],[1550905200000,1],[1550908800000,2],[1550912400000,4],[1550916000000,1],[1550919600000,4],[1550923200000,2],[1550926800000,1],[1550930400000,5],[1550934000000,1],[1550937600000,1],[1550941200000,1],[1550944800000,5],[1550948400000,1],[1550952000000,1],[1550959200000,3],[1550962800000,1],[1550966400000,1],[1550988000000,1],[1550991600000,2],[1550995200000,4],[1550998800000,5],[1551006000000,3],[1551009600000,4],[1551013200000,3],[1551016800000,3],[1551020400000,2],[1551024000000,3],[1551027600000,3],[1551031200000,2],[1551034800000,2],[1551038400000,3],[1551042000000,1],[1551045600000,1],[1551049200000,2],[1551052800000,1]],
"ty":[[1550880000000,4],[1550898000000,1],[1550908800000,1],[1550912400000,3],[1550916000000,2],[1550919600000,3],[1550923200000,2],[1550926800000,1],[1550930400000,2],[1550937600000,3],[1550941200000,4],[1550944800000,2],[1550948400000,2],[1550952000000,1],[1550955600000,1],[1550959200000,1],[1550962800000,2],[1550966400000,2],[1550995200000,3],[1550998800000,13],[1551002400000,1],[1551006000000,1],[1551013200000,4],[1551016800000,3],[1551024000000,1],[1551027600000,2],[1551031200000,1],[1551034800000,1],[1551038400000,3],[1551042000000,1],[1551049200000,5],[1551052800000,5]],
"wb":[[1550880000000,6],[1550887200000,1],[1550898000000,1],[1550912400000,1],[1550916000000,1],[1550919600000,1],[1550926800000,2],[1550930400000,1],[1550944800000,1],[1550991600000,1],[1550998800000,1],[1551016800000,1],[1551024000000,1],[1551027600000,1],[1551049200000,1],[1551052800000,1]],
"wf":[[1551034800000,1],[1551049200000,2],[1551052800000,2]],
"wn":[[1550880000000,16],[1550883600000,1],[1550898000000,1],[1550901600000,1],[1550905200000,2],[1550908800000,1],[1550912400000,1],[1550916000000,1],[1550919600000,1],[1550923200000,1],[1550934000000,1],[1550941200000,1],[1550944800000,1],[1550962800000,4],[1550966400000,4],[1550984400000,2],[1550988000000,1],[1550991600000,1],[1550995200000,1],[1551006000000,1],[1551009600000,2],[1551013200000,1],[1551049200000,19],[1551052800000,19]],
"in":[],"yt":[],"ot":[]}; //end data

//this part happens inside a SUCCESS statement in the AJAX call that retrieves the data above

//parse the returned data into the chart config above, substituting NULL values
     config.series[0].data = d.ig;
     config.series[1].data = d.tw;
     config.series[2].data = d.ty;
     config.series[3].data = d.wb;
     config.series[4].data = d.wn;
     config.series[5].data = d.wf;
     config.series[6].data = d.yt;
     config.series[7].data = d.in;
     config.series[8].data = d.ot;

//create the chart

     if(window.sourcesChart){
      window.sourcesChart.update(config);
    } else {
      window.sourcesChart = new Highcharts.chart('platformChartContainer', config);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your script for chart?

Comment: Could you reproduce it in online code editor like jsfiddle, codepen?

Comment: The original version implies ajax calls to a restricted API; this is a simplified version that reproduces the issue; data are real. https://jsfiddle.net/_dario/s3o61gj4/

Comment: So, it looks strange because your series data have different time intervals for points with the same index in data arrays. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/odz0rn6a/14/

Comment: zero data points are skipped altogether in the API output which probably doesn't help the renderer. Worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are a lot more gaps in the data at that level the disconnect between null values it more obvious. If you user the 'connectNulls' property on plotOptions.series it will make the chart a bit more readable.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    connectNulls: true
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ym8fn75x/

Comment: I wasn't aware of the connectNulls option; the curve fills still leave something to be desired and some points are still rendered as cusps, but the overall readability is _greatly_ improved. Probably reducing or avoiding null points altogether (see above) might help further improvement.